# Count numbers below 45 in a Linked List

Tags: java, data-structures, linked-list

I have this program:

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class MainProgram {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();

        list.add(45);
        list.add(10);
        list.add(47);
        list.add(41);
        list.add(2);

        System.out.println("Below 45 numbers are: "+Collections...);
    }
}
```

I want to count the numbers below 45, and print an asterisk for each. In my case, it was 3. So my program must display 3 asterisk.

> `***`

How will I do that?

Comment: What do you actually want? Calculate or display numbers below 45? Edit your post and make it clear.

Comment: I want to display numbers below 45.. and want to show it as using `*` symbol.

Comment: So for every number below 45 you want to print one '*'?

Comment: yes....................................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just loop through the list and print `*` every time a number is below 45

```
System.out.print("Below 45 numbers are: ");
for (int i : list) {
    if (i < 45) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
}
```

Comment: No problem. The more specific you are in the question the easier it is to help.